# Pass data received by WCF(SOAP) to the windows service to store in database

Tags: c#, wcf

My requirement is,  external client will consume the WCF and will send some data and i need to save this data in database using the Windows services, i have a separate windows service application which is already there in production which do the task to update the database, so i want the data received by WCF to send to the Windows service so that it can be saved in database.
external client always send data over HTTP/HTTPS SOAP XML.

i need to update the data and send the response back to Client.
I search lot find self hosting, named pipe,call back method but not getting the exact way how to do it.

So any help or guidance in this will be appreciable.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to host your WCF service inside your Windows Service where your Database logic reside. Something like this:

```
Uri[] adrbase = { new Uri("http://yourhost/service/")};
var YourService = new YourService (/*Pass your reference*/) // -> you can pass your windows service reference here or other link to your database.
var m_svcHost = new ServiceHost(YourService , adrbase);
```

For hosting WCF service inside your Windows service follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Example of wcf service :

```
public class YourService : IYourService 
{
    private readonly YourReference _yourReference;

    public YourService(yourReference /*Reference to your windows service or db*/)
    {
      _yourReference = yourReference;
    }

    public double Add(YourContract contract)
    {
        // Do you stuff here or pass the contract to your YourReference  for processing...
    }    
}
```

Comment: Here reference to windows service means i did not get you .

Comment: You need to revise your existing windows service and host your WCF service inside it.

Comment: private readonly YourReference _yourReference;

    public YourService(yourReference /*Reference to your windows service or db*/)
    {
      _yourReference = yourReference;
    } here windows service ref means what ?

Comment: It could be your windows service instance or db connection inside your windows service.